# “no valid 'aps-environment' entitlement string” when registering for Push Notifications

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, apple-push-notifications

i used the code below to register for push notification inside `applicationdidFinishLaunchingWithOptions` but nothing happens why ?

The code :

```
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:
 (UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound | UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert)];
```

and my Push Notification setting is on.

Comment: What do you expect to happen?

Comment: @zoul When the app starts and registers for push notifications, it shows a message to inform the user that this app wishes to send push notifications.

Comment: you want to inform the user every time he starts the app, that he might receive notifications?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you implement the `application:didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:` and `application:didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError:` delegate method to see how the registration ends?

Comment: Yes i implemented the 2 functions but now i notice this error Failed to get token, error: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3000 "no valid 'aps-environment' entitlement string found for application" UserInfo=0x2f24a0 {NSLocalizedDescription=no valid 'aps-environment' entitlement string found for application}

Comment: See, that’s easy. Google for the error and you’ll find out that you have a wrong provisioning profile (one that does not support APNS). Sometimes you have to “touch” the profile (like change the app name) on the provisioning website to make sure you are getting a fresh profile with APNS support. When you open the profile in a text editor you should find an `aps-environment` string there. Otherwise it won’t work.

Comment: @zoul - when you say "open the profile in a text editor" are you talking about the whatever.mobileprovision file?  because this file contains some kind of hex encoded data, essentially 466 1/2 rows of 8 groups of 4 hex characters separated by space (e.g. `4851 3842 4176 2845 0a09 01a2 404d 4382`).  Is this encoding new?  How can I view it?

Comment: Scroll down, there’s text data after the binary fluff.

Comment: @zoul Your answer saved my day! Have had trouble with push for a while. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You should also check wether your server is using the right target and the iOS the right certificate as well. There are two certificates: one is for development (sandbox certificate) and the other is the production certificate.

```
Development: gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195
Production: gateway.push.apple.com:2195
```

If you use the development certificate to talk to the production server address then you won't receive any push.

Also remind that the simulator doesn't support push. As it has no push token.

Comment: first i use my iphone device not the simulator, second the device didn't register for push i can find the app inside the list of push notifivation in settings

Comment: if you can find it in the notification setting then the app is already registered as application with push. you can use pushmebaby example to check wether the problem is on the server or not: [link](http://mobiforge.com/developing/story/programming-apple-push-notification-services)

Comment: sorry i want to say i can't, not can